# Проблема sleep freebasic

Tags: android, sleep, freebasic

1. Почему функция sleep в freebasic не работает на апп android basic compiler и как сделать чтобы работала? При этом ошибку не выдаёт

```
dim abc as String
abc="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

dim i as integer
for i=1 to 100
Print "abc"
sleep 3000,1
next
```

2. Где взять настоящий freebasic editor для андроид с поддержкой графики mode?

Comment: Во-первых, вопрос содержит несколько разных несвязанных вопросов. Их нужно задавать по отдельности. 

Во-вторых приведите ваш код.

Comment: Sleep 3000 просто не работает в freebasic. Код: for.... Print "a" sleep 3000

Comment: Ну так приведите код, который это демонстрирует, иначе вопрос закроют.

Comment: Отлично, я подправил еще ваш вопрос, но пожалуйста, приведите ошибку, которую выдает basic. Так положено по правилам сайта.

Comment: Я проверил, ваша программа отлично работает. Возможно вы пользуетесь устаревшим компилятором.

Comment: на android sleep не работает

Comment: ¯_(ツ)_/¯ Варианта два: или переходите работать на винду, или пишите разрабам ide, в которой работаете и ждите релиза с исправлением. Ну или бросайте вообще freebasic (никому он сейчас не нужен, его даже на tio.run нет).